# How to use addall in a list java

Tags: java, list, addition

Hello I have to add elements to my list and I notice if I Use the method add I just add the reference to my list but I would like to add the elements and not the reference:

```
ArrayList ArrayListIdle = new ArrayList();
List<State> arrayState = new ArrayList<State>();

while(rs.next){

state = new State();

state.updateStateArray(arrayState);//This function mods the elements of (arrayState);//This 
state.setArrayStates(arrayState);//add a list of arrayState to the object state


//I have a array and I want to add the element state with his arraylist(not the reference to)

ArrayListIdle.addAll(state);

// I tried with add , but in the next iteration the arrayState change.

}
```

Comment: I thought for a second that `ArrayListIdle` is a class where `addAll` is a static method. Is it so difficult to keep with conventions?

Comment: As Thomas pointed out, the Java naming convention is for variable names to start with a lower case letter. It makes the code easier to read. It's also quite confusing to have separate `updateStateArray` and `setStateArray` methods as it's not clear what each does. Perhaps this can be combined into one method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same `ArrayState` object every time. You should create a new `ArrayState` object every time in the `while` loop to avoid it getting changed every time. This is because by default objects are always passed by reference in Java. 
Try doing this:

```
ArrayList arrayListIdle = new ArrayList();


while(rs.next){

    state = new State();
    List<State> arrayState = new ArrayList<State>();

    state.updateStateArray(arrayState);//This function mods the elements of (arrayState);//This 
    state.setArrayStates(arrayState);//add a list of arrayState to the object state
    arrayListIdle.addAll(state);

}
```

Comment: The problem is arrayState have values I cant lost (the fuction UpdateStateArray  Made this function) ,

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Each state object will still reference this data populated by `updateStateArray`. You can still get it by calling `state.getArrayStates`.

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez The ArrayState objects won't be garbage collected after the end of for loop as you add them to the state.

Comment: the function updateArray take list with tree elements and copy the elemento number two inside the element number two, and the two in one, for I dont know if I right when I add the array to the state perfect I have the eleements for this state, but when in the next loop  If i made a  new list for arrayState im going to lost the values. Sorry if my english is not good enought

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez Could you clarify the question which list is the one that you want to add elements to and whats the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Thank Sapan and sorry If I not soo clear:
 state :- Have a array of states.
 arrayState :- Array of states .
 When I advance in the loop im adding the last state to "arrayState".
 With updateStateArray : I move the elements in the array.
 With setArrayState: y try to set the arrayState into (array into State)
 
    Problem : If a do   List<State> arrayState = new ArrayList<State>(); inside the loop 
 When i excecute the funtion update the arrayState is going to be empty.

Comment: If I understand you correctly `state.setArrayStates(new ArrayList<State>(arrayState))` will accomplish what you are looking for. This will only create a copy of the list structure, but the actual items in the list will point to the same state objects.

Comment: Now is not fixing my problem I have a question there is any form to add elementos to my array but the value and not the reference. </br>  because is going to be easy, </br>

Comment: And i was checking my code and when I create the consutructor of my State and in the variable array i have           this.arrayStatesAnteriores=null;  maybe here is the problem???

Comment: If you want to add the value and not the reference you need to call state.clone() before adding it to the list but you will have to implement it in your class.

Comment: Guys finnaly i resolve my dude the problem was I was defining to null the array inside my code for this reason in the next loop everything dissappear _D

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have one "arrayState" object and all of the state objects reference the same one.

One way to solve that here is to move the object creation inside loop so that a different object is created every time.

```
 while(rs.next) {
      List<State> arrayState = new ArrayList<State>();
      ...
 }
```